# NSThread suspend & resume

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have downloader application.
Application has two threads.
Main thread which contains all the UI.
Other thread is used for downloading files.

There are 3 buttons on window.
Start Download - To start download
Cancel Download - To cancel download

I have created download thread using following code

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(StartDownload) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Functionality is like when user click on "Pause Download" button, Message Box will be shown
to user asking "Do you want cancel downloading (Y/N)?" & download should be paused at this time. If your say no to cancel downloading then I want to resume downloading.

Problem is that I don't know how much time the user will take to respond to message box.

How do I achieve this kind suspend & resume with NSThread?

Thanks in advance,
Vaibhav

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard Unix sleep() and usleep() calls. or you can also use NSThread class method `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]`. this Sleeps the thread for a given time interval.

```
+ (void)sleepForTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti
```

You can display time with your message e.g. after 1min download will cancel. or display some counter.
**Note**:No run loop processing occurs while the thread is blocked.